# No Django settings specified. Unknown command: 'createsuperuser' Type 'manage.py help' for usage

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create a superuser through createsuperuser command in manage.py console is throwing an error "No Django settings specified. Also tried in python console by runninf python manage.py createsuperuser
Unknown command: 'createsuperuser'
Type 'manage.py help' for usage."

I AM USING PYCHARM

settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for MovieFlix project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 4.0.2.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/
"""
import os
from pathlib import Path


# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-#*8cdy*ul906(s4ei#g7h17)vv%)#0s5b##weupzn-&ct@ylez'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['192.168.2.12', '127.0.0.1']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'Core.apps.CoreConfig',
    'movie.apps.MovieConfig',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'MovieFlix.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'Core/templates')]
        ,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'MovieFlix.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
    # 'default': {
    #             'ENGINE': 'djongo',
    #             'NAME': 'MovieFlix',
    #             'ENFORCE_SCHEMA': False,
    #             'CLIENT': {
    #                 'host': 'mongodb+srv://movieflix:movieflix%401234@cluster0.fm15x.mongodb.net/MovieFlix?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
    #             }
    #         }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

manage.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Django's command-line utility for administrative tasks."""
import os
import sys


def main():
    """Run administrative tasks."""
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'MovieFlix.settings')
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: There is no bug seem to be in the files you posted but instead type ```python manage.py --help``` to see all of the available commands in ```manage.py```. Insure that you in project root directory where ```sqlite3.db and manage.py``` files live. If your issue did not get solved comment again.

Comment: i tried running python manage.py --help in manage.py, it still says no django settings specified

Comment: Is your ```python manage.py runserver``` working or not and you are in correct directory. If you are using windows , then in File Explorer go to your project you are working on and in ```address bar``` type ```cmd.exe``` and they try the commands.

Comment: i am using mac os, and pycharm i am running commands in manage.py@MovieFlix console

Comment: Have you tried ```python manage.py help```

Comment: in manage.py console i have used help command and it shows me the available commands. which are : check
    compilemessages
    createcachetable
    dbshell
    diffsettings
    dumpdata
    flush
    inspectdb
    loaddata
    makemessages
    makemigrations
    migrate
    runserver
    sendtestemail
    shell
    showmigrations
    sqlflush
    sqlmigrate
    sqlsequencereset
    squashmigrations
    startapp
    startproject
    test
    testserver\

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243551/discussion-between-shah-sawood-and-rizvi-ahmed-zillhaz).

Answer (score 0):

## In views.py

```
# Create your views here
def create_super_user(request):
    form = UserCreationForm()
    context = {"form": form}
    # When method is POST
    if request.method == "POST":
        # Populate form with data posted
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            try:
                user = form.save(commit=False)
                # Make the user as superuser
                user.is_superuser = 1
                # Make the user as staff
                user.is_staff = 1
                # Save the user to db
                user.save()
            except IntegrityError:
                return render(request, "register.djt", context)
            # Login the user after registration
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("home"))
        # When form is not valid
        return render(request, "register.djt", context)
    # When method is not POST
    return render(request, "app2/register.djt", context)
```

## In urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import create_super_user
urlpatterns = [
    path('register/', create_super_user, name="register"),
]
```

## In register.djt

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Create Super User</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2 class="text-center">Create Super User</h2>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <form method="POST" action="" class="row g-1">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form }}
                <input type="submit" value="Register" class="btn btn-primary">
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

after having all of the above code then visit the url `register/` to create a super user.